# Dynamic Data foreign key table display name

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql, dynamic-data

I have these two tables in my diagram:

the 1st:
**PAR_TipiDocumento** with
idTipoDocumento PK
idClasseDocumento
[...]

the 2nd:
**PAR_ClassiDocumento** with
idClasseDocumento PK
[...]

and a foreing key FK_PAR_TipiDocumento_PAR_ClassiDocumento from PAR_TipiDocumento.idClasseDocumentoto PAR_ClassiDocumento.idClasseDocumento.

This is my .cs code for the metadata:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(PAR_TipiDocumento_Metadata))]
[DisplayName("Tipi Documento")]
public partial class PAR_TipiDocumento
{
    [DisplayName("Tipi Documento")]
    [TableName("Tipi Documento")]        
    [ScaffoldTable(true)]
    public class PAR_TipiDocumento_Metadata
    {
        [Display(Name = "Classe Documento", Order = 1)]
        public object PAR_ClassiDocumento { get; set; }

        /* other fields*/
    }
}


[MetadataType(typeof(PAR_ClassiDocumento_Metadata))]
[DisplayName("Classi Documento")]
public partial class PAR_ClassiDocumento
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Codice.ToString() + " - " + Descrizione.ToString();
    }

    [TableName("Classi Documento")]
    [ScaffoldTable(true)]
    public class PAR_ClassiDocumento_Metadata
    {
        /* other fields*/
    }
}
```

The problem is that in the Dynamic Data generated pages I correctly see all the display names "Tipi Documento" except for the header row of the PAR_ClassiDocumento table where I have "PAR_TipiDocumentos" (the plural generated by LINQ to SQL). The values under this column are correctly rendered as links to the PAR_TipiDocumento table with the right display name ("View Tipi Documento").

How can I change the Display Name of that "PAR_TipiDocumentos"?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found how to obtain this.

I just needed to add this attribute:

```
    [TableName("Classi Documento")]
    [ScaffoldTable(true)]
    public class PAR_ClassiDocumento_Metadata
    {
        /* other fields */

        [Display(Name = "Tipi Documento collegati")]
        public object PAR_TipiDocumentos { get; set; }

    }
```